# How to handle different series of data in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I am using nvd3's multibar chart. The problem is the series I provide to the chart is not symmetrical. Like there will be values for a some series and others won't have.

```
[
  {
    "key": "ALL POS",
    "color": "#39a5cf",
    "values": [
      {
        "x": "4/01/2012",
        "y": 54,
        "series": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "MIX POS",
    "color": "#2227f4",
    "values": [
      {
        "x": "4/01/2012",
        "y": 34,
        "series": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "PURE POS",
    "color": "#9fa9f7",
    "values": []
  }
]
```

You can see the pure pos series doesnt have values compared to the other two. Because of this the stacked effect is not working. Can someone help me regarding this?

Comment: i know it's pretty old, but have you find a way around this ? i'm getting the same problem :(